# I want to switch between versions 2 & 3 of Python. Both are installed

Tags: python

If I double click on a .py file it opens "IDLE" (is there another way to open "IDLE"?), but the default python version is 2 when I select "run". I want to PERMANENTLY change the default version to 3 so that I don't have to switch versions every time I switch on my Raspberry Pi.

I have searched for this without success. Most answers predate the inclusion of Python 3 and explain how to install 3 but NOT how to switch the default, hence this question.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling python 2?

Comment: @Bex, I would not uninstall py2 unless you're certain that it is not needed elsewhere. There are still many scripts out there that run on 2.7.

Answer (score 5):

`IDLE` is usually installed along with `python`, so you should have `idle3` somewhere. Here's what you should do:

1. Try to run `idle3`, `idle3.3`, `idle3.4` etc. in the terminal to make sure you have it. Let's assume you have `idle3`
2. Change the file association of `.py` files, so they are opened with `idle3` when double-clicked. This depends on your file manager, usually righ-click -> "Open With..." does the trick.

Again, playing with symlinks is not a good idea, because scripts starting with `#!/usr/bin/python` expect to be executed with `python2`.

Answer (score -2):

a **proper** way to do it is to use Debain's [update-alternatives](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives)

UPD: people are too lazy to jyst **R**ead **T**he **F**ine **M**anual :

```
update-alternatives --remove-all python
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/python2/bin/python2 10
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/python3/bin/python3 20
```

That's the way it should be. After that to switch the things up :

```
update-alternatives --set python "/usr/python2/bin/python2"
```

to select the one you need. It *won't* break [PEP-394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), because `python2` and `python3` binaries will be where they **must** be in multi-versioned install : in the installations' prefixes(`usr/python2` and `/usr/python3` respectively)

Comment: There is no link group for Python in `update-alternatives`.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: `update-alternatives` are just a nice way to track symlinks in your system, so in the end your solution will hit the same problem as @Milliways': you'll replace `/usr/bin/python`, which is a violation of PEP-394.

Comment: @n.st So you need to create it =) That's the idea : no package mess-up, standard switching mode

Comment: I don't know the internals of `update-alternatives` all that well, but wouldn't creating a custom link group mess up with packages which are unaware of it? When you update `python2`, wouldn't this package overwrite the symlink `update-alternatives` created?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev if you don't need to maintain multiple versions of gen-2 and gen-3 inside a branch, for example you need v2.7 and v3.0, not v2.6, v2.7 and v3.0,v3.1 - you don't need to touch a `python2` and `python3` links AT ALL : just add the corresponding dirs in your PATH **and** delete a `python` symlink in the `xxx/bin` folders

Comment: PEP-394 specifically says that `/usr/bin/python` should point to python2, because many legacy scripts starting with `#!/usr/bin/python` only run correctly with python2.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev legacy scripts are DOOMED OUT : they're not working with a modern libraries/components. It should not bother you unless you're a musemum sysadmin =)

Comment: OK, point taken. BTW, thanks for expanding your answer, I'm happy to upvote it now even if I don't totally agree.